# How to increase scan speed on Firemonkey (TEdit Component)

Tags: android, delphi, barcode, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

My question is just about reading value from EAN13 barcode to **TEdit** field. I developed an android application with Delphi Firemonkey which should read 1D Ean13 barcode then it'll process with databases after all give us a result which is correct or not.

Basically, I'm using stored procedure for making these steps but in Firemonkey form, my **TEdit field is too slow** for 1D barcode scanner. My beta test device is *Urovo i6200s*. *Android version is 4.1.2*

Now, I'm trying to increase scan speed but I couldn't do it in FMX. Webservice is calling result in 0.0052 second. But **TEdit needs almost 2.5 seconds** for writing my value to **Edit1.Text**

By the way I tried to scan my barcode and write it to Default Android Browser and input field in Message application, the result is so fast like my webservice results. Also I tried to write Edit1 without Event references, it's still very very slow.

Is there any solution, optimization or anything I can do?

Edit: Here is my code for asking: But this is not about my code. Its about **TEdit**.

```
procedure TfrmMain.eBarcodeChangeTracking(Sender: TObject);
var
  result: integer;
begin
  lblStatus.Text := '';

  if eBarcode.Text.Length = 12 then
  begin
    result := -1;
    try
      result := MyService.CheckBarcode(eBarcode.Text);
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        ShowMessage('Error occurred while reading barcode');
      end;

    end;

    eBarcode.Text := '';

    if result = 0 then
    begin
      lblStatus.Text := 'OK';
    end else 
      lblStatus.Text := 'Failed';
  end;
end;
```

end;

Comment: How can we even start to offer suggestions on how to optimize code we can't see?

Comment: I mean "how to increase **reading speed to TEdit**, not in my code. As I said before, If there is no code or no event references (which means there is no code for calling), it is too slow. Only problem is just about speed. My code is fine. It is working good in Windows but not in Android with FMX.

Comment: Surely the `TEdit` is not the problem.

Comment: How is your barcode scanner inputting its results into your TEdit? Does it simulates key events like most barcode scanner does? If it does when/where are you processing that barcode in your databases? I seriously hope you are firing database check in OnChange event as this will cause the TEdit contents to be checked in your database for each inputted character which could cause considerable delay before the application is ready for new input.

Comment: Dear @J..., I've tried to write anything but there is some lag. This device is industrial designed device which means its expensive and succesful. I used Default Android Browser and it scanned in several miliseconds, also I tried in message application, there was same speed. Also there is an scanner application came with device automatically, Scanner app is so fast but TEdit remains in class.

Comment: @SilverWarior, I updated my post with my code.

Comment: Are you modifying the `eBarcode.Text` property in its own `OnChange` handler?  Surely that's in extreme danger of ending up in a recursive loop.  Also, how can `eBarcode.Text.Length = 12` right after you have set `eBarcode.Text = ''`?

Comment: I agree with J... Also instead of using OnChange event and checking the text length for each inputted character you might be better of by using OnKeyPress event waiting for special ending character (usually a new line character) that is returned at the end by most barcode scanners. This way you also give yourself an ability to potentially use other barcode formats in the future since you are not hardcoding the key length. Check your barcode scanner documentation to see if it does return that ending character and what character it is.

Comment: @J... This is EAN13 Barcode. Ean13 is 12 characters. If users try to read different barcodes, they will not work like I wanted. Also pre-defined real barcodes are in my database and .net webservice is executing a result as true or false.

Comment: @J... if I create a new FMX Application, then I create a new TEdit then compile my application, it is getting same result. I mean if there is no code, it should work fast, right? but its still too slow. If you have any 1D barcode reader and android device, you can try what i said.

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: @J... Delphi XE8 Professional with Mobile Addon Pack

Comment: That's really odd, then - what if you just type with a keyboard or other input device?  Is the input response really that slow?  ~4-5 characters per second?

Comment: Make a [mcve] to demonstrate the issue